# Connect with SQL Server Management Studio to testcontainer created with MsSqlTestcontainer

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, testcontainers

I am running test with xunit, specflow and testcontainer to create a database in memory. When Dapper executes the query, I get this error:

In docker desktop I see the database in memory:

[image]

[image]

This is the code of the test that create the database in memory:

```
[Given("a valid file request (.*)")]
public void GivenAValiFileUploaded()
{
    var testcontainersBuilder = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
            .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
            {
                Password = "Sup3r.Str0ng.P4ss"
            });

    var testcontainersBuild = testcontainersBuilder.Build();
    testcontainersBuild.StartAsync();

    var body = GetFile(fileName);
    _scenarioContext.Set(body, "Body");
}
```

Does someone know how we can get the connection string of this database in memory in docker desktop or in other anywhere?

Is there a way to get this connection string from code in c# to override the connection string placed in `appsettings.json` (test project)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that the screenshots you share indicate no in-memory database whatsoever. They show Testcontainer's Ryuk sidecar container, which is responsible for cleaning up resources.

Comment: Don't know if you solved this but the connnection string data source needs to be formatted as such DataSource = $@"127.0.0.1\{DatabaseContainer.Name[1..]}, {DatabaseContainer.Port}" where DatabaseContainer.Name is the name of the container created and obviously the port assigned to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample to get the connection string.

```
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Builders;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Configurations;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Containers;

var testcontainersBuilder = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
    .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
    {
        Password = "Sup3r.Str0ng.P4ss"
    });

await using (var testcontainers = testcontainersBuilder.Build())
{
    await testcontainers.StartAsync(); // This can take a while
    Console.WriteLine(testcontainers.ConnectionString);
}
```

Also checkout the [examples](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet#examples) in the documentation.

With this value you could then create an in process environment variable or [in memory application setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#memory-configuration-provider).

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddInMemoryCollection(new []{
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionStringName",testcontainers.ConnectionString),
      // Other values or providers
   })
  .Build();
```